# Is there a way to prevent the default constructor of a class from running for a single instance of a member variable?

Tags: c++, opengl

For my game, suppose I have a class called GameTexture, where the default constructor looks like this:

```
GameTexture::GameTexture() {
    this->shader = ShaderManager::get_instance()->get_shader("2d_texture", "2d_texture", "", 0);
}
```

get_shader() looks like this:

```
Shader* ShaderManager::get_shader(std::string vertex, std::string fragment, std::string geometry, unsigned int features) {
    if (!shader_map.contains(vertex)
    || !shader_map[vertex].contains(fragment)
    || !shader_map[vertex][fragment].contains(geometry)
    || !shader_map[vertex][fragment][geometry].contains(features)) {
        shader_map[vertex][fragment][geometry][features].init(vertex, fragment, geometry, features);
    }
    return &shader_map[vertex][fragment][geometry][features];
}
```

and initializing a shader starts like this:

```
void Shader::init(std::string vertex_dir, std::string fragment_dir, std::string geometry_dir, unsigned int features) {
    ShaderManager* shader_manager = ShaderManager::get_instance();
    id = glCreateProgram();
```

Note that it's not safe to set the shader to nullptr by default, because then if we ever attempt to render an unloaded GameTexture, the program will immediately crash upon trying to dereference the nullptr. So instead, we set it to a default shader that won't cause any damage even if everything else about the texture is the default. On its own this is fine, but it becomes a problem if we ever load a GameTexture before OpenGL has been initialized. Suppose we add another singleton called RenderManager. RenderManager is responsible for creating a window, loading OpenGL, etc. Suppose it looks like this:

```
class RenderManager {
public:
    RenderManager(RenderManager& other) = delete;
    void operator=(const RenderManager& other) = delete;

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* sdl_renderer;
    SDL_GLContext sdl_context;
    int s_window_width;
    int s_window_height;

    GameTexture example_texture;

    static RenderManager* get_instance();
    void destroy_instance();
private:
    RenderManager();
    static RenderManager* instance;
};

RenderManager::RenderManager() {
    float width = 1920.0;
    float height = 1080.0;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP);
    SDL_GetWindowSize(window, &s_window_width, &s_window_height);
    sdl_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE | SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    sdl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW!" << std::endl;
    }
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, sdl_context);
    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    example_texture.init("example/path/here.png");
}
```

Suppose we start to create an instance of the RenderManager. Before calling the constructor, it goes through all of its members and finds example_texture. It calls the constructor for example_texture, which tells it to get a shader. ShaderManager hasn't already loaded that shader, so it starts to do so. However, this causes the program to crash because it's calling glCreateProgram() despite OpenGL not yet having been loaded.

Which leads me to my question. I know that I'm going to manually initialize this specific instance of a GameTexture, and in fact in this case I'm required to seeing as how the program trying to create the GameTexture on its own doesn't work, so is there any possible way to force the constructor not to run for this specific instance of a GameTexture without deleting it outright? That way it could be stored in the RenderManager as a member variable, but it wouldn't try to call any gl functions before gl was loaded.

Note that I'm aware that there are other solutions to this which I'm willing to do. If I were to heap-allocate this GameTexture, its constructor wouldn't run until I actually allocated it. That's the approach I'm currently taking, but I'm not happy with the idea of heap-allocating just to use it like a stack-allocated variable in all contexts when no other GameTextures are on the heap to begin with.

Comment: Why does a "GameTexture" have a "shader"? Shaders and textures are in no way directly linked.

Comment: For the sake of modularity; GameTextures being able to know which shader they'll use to render on a per-instance basis keeps things organized rather than keeping a separate list somewhere mapping which shader is used for each texture (or hardcoding it, which would spiral out of control incredibly quickly). Everything that renders needs to be able to use a shader though, so it makes sense to default it to one that works for the bare essentials.

Comment: When singletons have a dependency on other singletons, you either need to wrap everything in a singleton manager that controls the lifetime / initialization ordering, or you introduce some other dependency whereby one singleton can only be accessed via an interface that ensures its dependent singletons are already initialized. Otherwise it's a free-for-all, and you'll wind up with technical debt by relying on assumed knowledge of "the way", which I guarantee will cause pain in the near or distant future.

Comment: Step 1 is **figure out what you want the computer to do**. You sound a bit confused because you want the computer to create a shader before initializing OpenGL. That's obviously not possible so what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: What I want the computer to do is not try creating a shader for this specific texture until I get to it manually. I will go on to initialize the texture myself later down the line, but it existing as a member at all means that the owning class cannot construct itself. Default constructors will attempt to initialize themselves once the owning class is declared, but those same constructors will crash if the owning class hasn't constructed itself first.

Comment: Also @paddy the RenderManager doesn't directly rely on ShaderManager. If a GameTexture tried to generate its own Shader internally, that would also cause issues because it'd still be "The default constructors for a class's members ran, but those default constructors won't start working until the constructor for the class itself has been called." As mentioned, I can prevent the default constructor from running if the member is heap-allocated after proper dependencies have been loaded, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler alternative.

Comment: @HenryNissen It also looks like you're painting yourself into a corner by assuming you have to use classes a certain way. You might want to consider *not* using them this way. For example, what if you allow a null texture object and null shader object, only containing their own filenames, then you go and load all the textures and shaders when the game loads?

Comment: The way to prevent the default constructor from running is to call a different constructor. Or don't put the code in the constructor that you don't want to run. The point of a constructor is that you have to run one, so if you don't want to always run it then don't make it the only constructor?

Comment: @HenryNissen You're missing the point. If GameTexture relies on ShaderManager, and ShaderManager relies on the renderer being initialized, then your dependencies are not correctly represented in code. One option is to not allow a default GameTexture at all. Delete that constructor, and add a method in ShaderManager that returns your empty texture. The ShaderManager should be held by the RenderManager, or as I suggested something more centralized that manages their correct ordering. I'm not gonna sit here in comments and argue about it though.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of having constructors is that you have to run one. If you don't want to run one constructor, you have to run a different constructor. If you don't have a different constructor, you have to add one. Or, move the code you don't want to run in the constructor, so it isn't in the constructor, but somewhere else.

You seem to have painted yourself into a corner by *insisting* that you have to have classes that act a certain way. You want every shader object to actually be a shader (not null); you want to get a shader in every texture object; you want to create a texture object before OpenGL has been initialized; and you can't get a shader until after OpenGL has been initialized. **It is impossible to satisfy all these requirements.** You have to change one.

One possibility is that you change the requirement that all textures have to have a shader object. I would consider creating the texture object in a null state and then loading the actual texture into it later (as you seem to be already doing!) and loading the shader at the same time. I've done this before. It is not too difficult to make a linked list of all the `texture` objects that exist, then when OpenGL is loaded, you go through them all and actually load the textures.

Another suggestion is that you don't create the texture object until after OpenGL has been initialized. Initialize OpenGL, then create all the textures. If that means your window and your game rendering have to be in two separate classes, so be it. If you make a `Window` class and put a `Window window;` inside `class RenderManager` - before `GameTexture example_texture;` - the constructor for `Window` will run before the constructor for `GameTexture`. Then you'll have OpenGL initialized when you go to create the texture and shader.

---

Extras:

In fact it's kinda weird that you don't know when your window will be created. Normally you want to know which order your code runs in, surely? Create the window, then initialize OpenGL, then load the level file, then load all the textures for the level, then send the message saying "a new player has joined the game." - trying to make all this happen in the right order without actually saying the order is *sometimes* a recipe for disaster. You might have caught "singleton fever" and be trying to do some fancy class shenanigans instead of *just. telling. the. computer. what. you. want. it. to. do*. It's okay, everyone goes through that phase.

Another thing I noticed is that textures aren't usually associated with shaders. Generally, *materials* are associated with shaders - a material being a shader and all the textures it needs. Some shaders use zero textures (like a distortion effect); some use multiple (like a diffuse colour texture and also a normal map).